# R - aggregate with additional argument

Tags: r, aggregation, function

I would like to use the function aggregate (R raster package) to assign to a grid point of the new raster the number of grid points of the old raster that have a certain value

```
for(val in 1:10)
{
    new.raster <- aggregate(old.raster, 10, fun = function(x) length(x[x == val], na.rm=TRUE))

    #...some computation involving new.raster...
}
```

I've moved "na.rm = TRUE" around in every way imaginable, but R keeps complaining about an "Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)". Any ideas?

If it's possible to write this piece of code in a more efficient manner (having the function fun outside the aggregate function, or the like), I'd be happy if you could let me know as well, as I'm running the code for a very large number of rasters.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
 The function ‘fun’ should take multiple numbers, and return a
 single number. For example ‘mean’, ‘modal’, ‘min’ or ‘max’.  It
 should also accept a ‘na.rm’ argument (or ignore it as one of the
 'dots' arguments).
```

You've just got `function(x)`, which has neither an `na.rm` or dots in it.

Try:

```
new.raster <- aggregate(old.raster, 10, fun = function(x,...) length(x[x == val]))
```

to ignore whatever `na.rm` is passed through to it, or:

```
new.raster <- aggregate(old.raster, 10, fun = function(x, na.rm) length(x[x == val]))
```

to (maybe) pass through any `na.rm` in the `aggregate` call.

Note untested, because no reproducible example.. But it looks right.

Also, instead of `length(x[x==val])` you might be better with `sum(x==val, na.rm=na.rm)` and then you can pass the `na.rm` through to handle possible NA in your data.

Comment: Both suggestions result in "Error in length([...]) :  2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1"

Comment: Ah yes, get rid of the `na.rm` in your call to `length` because it doesn't take that parameter - see edit.